# How to configure my action method which should have same route, same controller but only the verb changes in dotnetcore webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to invoke the respective action method of the same controller given, route is same for both the action methods but only the http verb changes.

```
public class TestController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{param1}/{param2}")]
    public string MethodWithGet(string param1, string param2)
    {
       return interalgetmethodcall(param1, param2);
    }

    [HttpPost("{param1}/{param2}")]
    public string MethodWithPost(string param1, string param2,[FromBody] dynamic datafrombody)
    {
       return interalpostmethodcall(param1, param2, datafrombody.toString());
    }
}
```

When I try to do a get call, the return from the appropriate method is returned. But when I try to make a post call, this is giving 500 Internal server error.

Is there a way I can use both method with same route, same controller but different httpverb to work?

Comment: `datafrombody` is most likely null

Comment: your route names are correct, put a breakpoint in the post method and check your parameters. and avoid dynamic parameter in your method argument, use string.

Comment: For the love of all things good and holy, don't post to a `dynamic`. Create a class with properties matching the data you're posting and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding something about Rest API.

When you're using GET verb you should pass the data via url parameters. When you use POST verb the recommend way is to pass data via body.

So you could convert your method headers to:

```
    [HttpGet("{param1}/{param2}")]
    public string MethodWithGet(string param1, string param2)
    {
       return interalgetmethodcall(param1, param2);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string MethodWithPost([FromBody]string param1, [FromBody]string param2,[FromBody] dynamic datafrombody)
    {
       return interalpostmethodcall(param1, param2, datafrombody.toString());
    }
```

The first one you'll call like this:

```
fetch(`/${param1}/${param2}`, {method: 'GET'});
```

and the second one would be:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("param1", param1);
formData.append("param2", param2);
formData.append("datafrombody", datafrombody);
fetch('/', {method: 'POST', body: formData});
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to do a get call, the return from the appropriate method is returned. But when I try to make a post call, this is giving 500 Internal server error.

You could use the same route, same controller with different httpverb.

Here are my test result.

Reust From Postman
[image]
[image]
Result in VS
[image]
Your issue maybe cuased by `interalpostmethodcall(param1, param2, datafrombody.toString());`, try

```
    interalpostmethodcall(param1, param2, datafrombody?.toString());
```

In addition, enable `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in `Startup.cs` to check detail error.